# react hook invoke child method from parent on-demand without forwardRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in react hooks, what can i do while avoiding rewriting a child component as a [`forwardRef()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef) (an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950970/1184717)) but be able to invoke on-demand (e.g. on button click) a method in the child from the parent component.

i hope the following snippet will explain better what i would like to achieve ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-perlman-krfuq2)).

Child.js

```js
// Child.js

export default function Child() {
  const val = "child val";
  const getVal = () => val;
}
```

App.js:

```js
// App.js

import Child from "./Child";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(childRef.current.getVal());
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>button</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `forwardRef`?

Comment: @Unmitigated to avoid rewriting a child component

Comment: You could pass the ref through a different prop I suppose. Would that help?

Comment: @Unmitigated maybe, don't fully understand what you mean. do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ref to the child component through a separate prop.

```
function Child({_ref}) {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    _ref.current = {getVal};
  }, [_ref]);
  return "Child content";
}
// ...
<Child _ref={childRef} />
```

You can also set the ref inside the child component with `useImperativeHandle` like so:

```js
useImperativeHandle(_ref, () => ({getVal}), [/* dependencies */]);
```